# Vectors in 3dimensions

Tags: vectors

[image]

I have the following question - how do I derive the point exactly halfway between the 4 posts? I tried looking at midpoint theorem, diagonal intersection and intersection of two lines but got stuck at every turn. Any advice on this would really be appreciated.

For the second part although I can't proceed quite yet, I know that after finding the mid-point (above) I'll have to find the direction using (3, -2, 4) and the found point, can someone also advise if this is correct?

Thank you

Comment: I think you will need to define the vertical line that is midway between the two vertical posts and the horizontal line that is midway between the two horizontal posts.  And then find the line that goes through your starting point and the two lines.  The point where it will need to go through these lines will vary depending on where the shot is taken from.

Comment: @turkeyhundt I understand that I'd have to do that but the problem is how? Any websites or theorems would really be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing out loud here, but the path needs to go through
$(3,-2,4)$, 
$(-10,0,z)$, and 
$(-12,y,0)$

So using the ratios of the $x$ coordinate would it go through $(3,-2,4)$, 
$(-10,0,\frac{8}{15})$, and 
$(-12,\frac{4}{13},0)$ so you could get the direction from that?

I'll think about it a little more...

Comment: sounds very plausible, thank you very much. please let me know if you thought of anything else!

Comment: how did you get 8/15 and 4/15? Been trying to work out how u got that but no luck so far

Comment: I was thinking that the x value went from 3 to -10 to -12 so it travels $\frac{13}{15}$ of it's distance on the first leg and $\frac{2}{15}$ on the second leg.  So, where I had $\frac{4}{15}$ it should be $\frac{4}{13}$.  I think that the $\frac{8}{15}$ is correct.

Comment: that's very helpful! thank you